# Tensor flow Neural Network error

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I am running a Neural Network algorithm on a dataset but am running into errors.I am not sure what this error means or how to fix it. The dataset is simply
1 0 1
0 1 0  and so forth where the third column would be the category that I am classifying. My code is below:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import urllib

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

Stock_TRAINING = "Stocks.csv"
Stock_TEST = "Workbook2.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=Stock_TRAINING,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.int)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=Stock_TEST,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.int)


# Specify that all features have real-value data
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[2])]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                          hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                          n_classes=2,
                                          model_dir="/tmp/stocks")

# Define the training inputs
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": np.array(training_set.data)},
    y=np.array(training_set.target),
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)

# Train model.
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=2000)

# Define the test inputs
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": np.array(test_set.data)},
    y=np.array(test_set.target),
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)

# Evaluate accuracy.
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn)["accuracy"]

print("\nTest Accuracy: {0:f}\n".format(accuracy_score))

# Classify two new stock samples.
new_samples = np.array(
    [[1, 0],
    [1,1]
    [0,0],
    [0,1],
    [1, 1]], dtype=np.float32)

predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": new_samples},
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)

predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn))
predicted_classes = [p["UpDown"] for p in predictions]

print("Stock is Up or Down Next Day:    {}\n"
      .format(predicted_classes))
```

when I run this code, I get the following error which is occurring in the `classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=2000)`

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((64, 1) vs (128, 1))
```

Please let me know if you need to see the full error message or need anything else.

Comment: Print here `training_set.data.shape` and `training_set.target.shape`.

Comment: apperently your labels (I guess training_set.target) seem to have a higher dimension (128) than the output layer of your network (64).